# language varieties that are languages

Tags: english, terminology, linguistic-typology, sociolinguistics

> **Language varieties**
>
> Any set of linguistic forms which patterns according to social factors: i.e. used under
> specific social circumstances. The term includes different accents, different linguistic
> styles, different dialects and even different languages which contrast with each other for
> social reasons.
>
> **Language**
>
> a language can be thought of as a collection of dialects that are
> usually linguistically similar, used by different social groups who
> choose to say that they are speakers of one language which functions
> to unite and represent them to other groups.
>
> **Pidgin**
>
> A pidgin is a language which has no native speakers.
>
> **Creole**
>
> A pidgin which has acquired native speakers and has consequently
> expanded in structure (grammar and vocabulary) in order to express the
> range of meanings and functions required of a first language.
>
> **Lingua franca**
>
> A language serving as a means of
> communication between speakers
> whose first languages differ.
>
> **Standard variety / Standard Language / Standard dialect**
>
> Language variety which generally has a written form and which has undergone some
> degree of codification. It is the variety taught in schools and has high prestige. It is
> generally regarded by the community as the ‘correct’ variety.
>
> **Nonstandard dialect / Vernacular dialect**
>
> Linguistic forms or varieties that do not conform to the standard.

These definitions are from *An Introduction to Sociolinguistics* by *Janet Holmes* and *Nick Wilson*.

I know pidgin, creole, lingua franca, standard dialect and vernacular dialect are all language varieties, but are they languages?

Comment: It's not totally clear to me, if you asking if creole, pidgin, lingua franca and others are a complete system that be can be defined as a language and are different from each other, like for example, portuguese, french and spanish, or if you are asking if they are different dialects/expressions of one specific language.
Which one your question is about?

Comment: I think it's the former.

Answer (score 0):

There is no curent consensus about the distinction between a language and a dialect, and their exact definition varies depending on the time and authors. Like Max Weinreich said, [a language is a dialect with an army and navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_language_is_a_dialect_with_an_army_and_navy).

I think however that the definitions of Pidgin, Creole and Lingua Franca you gave are more consensual and pretty much commonly accepted. A Creole is definitely a language since it's technically not a dialect, but there might be a line to draw with some lingua franca that might not be developped enough to be considered as a language. Once again, nothing consensual as far as I know.

Comment: If "language" and "dialect" can be used interchangeably, then is it correct to say that lingua franca, pidgin and creole are all languages / dialects?

Comment: I didn't say they were interchangeable, simply that the distinction between them is blurry and non-consensual. A creole is definitely a language, but a lingua franca/pidgin may or may not be considered one depending on its complexity and development. Some lingua franca are closer to a dialectal variation (only a few nouns from one language, everything else from the other) than a full language. It really depends

Comment: So does it suffice to say that a dialect / language could be a lingua franca, pidgin and creole, and a lingua franca, pidgin and creole must be either a dialect or a language?